# How to implement observer in swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following project which implements an observer in swift in order to pass data between two Views.

Model

```
import Foundation

class ModelData : ObservableObject {
@Published var number: Int = 1
}
```

View1

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct SliderView: View {

@State private var text = "1"
@State private var isEditing = false
@State private var celsius: Double = 1

@StateObject var modelData = ModelData()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Number from slider: \(Int(round(celsius)), specifier: "%d")")
            
            Slider(value: $celsius,
                   in: 1...20, step:1.0)
        }.onChange(of: celsius) { _ in
        
            self.text = String(Int(round(celsius)))
            self.modelData.number = Int(round(celsius))
        }
        
        HStack {
            Text("Number")
            Spacer()
            Text(String(text))
        }.padding()
    }
    }
    }

    struct SliderView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
    SliderView()
    }
    }
```

View2

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
@ObservedObject var modelData = ModelData()

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.red
        VStack {
        Image("Settings")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .font(.system(size: 100.0))
            Text(String(format: "Number is %d ", modelData.number))
        }
    }
    
}
}
```

The SettingsView is not updated when data is changed inside SliderView and it remains with the default value of ModelData.

Best regards,
Aurelian

Comment: both views are not connected to each other and you are creating two different objects of your model data class. you have to use binding like connection. Add more details how your views are connected to each other.

Comment: Make a parent view of both as an owner/holder of ModelData and inject that same instance into your views (SliderView, SettingsView, etc.) via init.

Comment: the views are tabItems inside a TabView. i did not connect one each other

Comment: In the View with your `TabView`, declare `@StateObject var modelData = ModelData()` 
and pass it to `View1` using `.environmentObject(modelData)`. In `View1` use 
`@EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData`. Do the same for `View2`.

Comment: Could you put also this comment as a response? It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the View with your `TabView`,
declare `@StateObject var modelData = ModelData()`

and pass it to `View1` using `.environmentObject(modelData)`.

In `View1` use `@EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData`. Do the same for `View2`.